# How best to handle a long list of items to rate?

Tags: gui-design, interface

I have a site where one feature is where people list their skills and rate them in two ways. This often turns into a very long list, which makes the task of not only adding but rating each one daunting. I would love to make this interface a lot more engaging and easier to handle, but I'm running short on ideas at the moment. Nothing is out of the realm of possibility in terms of UX, but I would love for an idea that is simple and intuitive (and fun, hopefully!)

Currently it's a typical text input with a typeahead and some clickable suggestions underneath that get added to a vertical list with the two ways to rate (like/meh/dislike and no experience/novice/intermediate/advanced/master).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create X,Y axes to represent the rating space and allow different means of "dropping" skills in a particular spot:

1. Clicking in a spot pulls up the typeahead you've described.
2. Alongside "graph", provide a list of common or relevant skills that the user can drag and drop into the graph. You might provide a category selector to pull up different subsets of skills and also modify the list based on direct entry skills. (ie if a user clicks and types 'CSS' directly, populate the list with 'Sass', 'HTML', etc.)

Comment: this has got me thinking about some awesome ideas, thanks

Comment: Great! I'm not sure how intuitive the 2-D rating space is, but it would eliminate two explicit actions required of the user.